# Install and Set Up kubectl - Kubernetes

Tags: centos, centos7, yum, kubernetes

I'm trying to follow [Install and Set Up kubectl - Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-binary-using-native-package-management), yet keep getting an error:

```
# yum --quiet install kubectl
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized."
Trying other mirror.
It was impossible to connect to the CentOS servers.
This could mean a connectivity issue in your environment, such as the requirement to configure a proxy,
or a transparent proxy that tampers with TLS security, or an incorrect system clock.
You can try to solve this issue by using the instructions on https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors
If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.



 One of the configured repositories failed (Kubernetes),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=kubernetes ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable kubernetes
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=kubernetes

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=kubernetes.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from kubernetes: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized."
#
```

I also tried using `curl` to access same URL and got following:

```
# curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
#
```

Is there a way to use `-k/--insecure` in yum's repo file somehow?

Please advise.

Comment: You should _fix_ the problem, not just insecurely work around it. Try reinstalling `ca-certificates`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you're absolutely correct, however this time, I just need to by pass it without verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have some kind of proxy which intercepts your tls connections.

However, it is possible to bypass certificate check in yum, you can put this line in your Kubernetes repo config:

> sslverify = 0

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two lines from your `kubernetes.repo` file:

```
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
```

It worked for me. These verify package signatures after the download.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! You can also bypass this in the kubernetes.repo file by changing **repo_gpgcheck** to:

```
repo_gpgcheck=0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).